# What is the difference between Router and Annotated Controllers?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm using WebFlux for Web development.
And I find 2 ways to express request mappings.

1. Annotated Controllers: Like `@Controller` or `@RestController`.
2. `RouterFunction`: `RouterFunction` is used to route requests to a `HandlerFunction`.

I find the second harder to use than the first and also I do not know the difference between them.

So I wanted to ask which performs better 2 or 1 ?

Thanks my friends!

Comment: '@RestControlle' = '@Controller'  + '@ResponseBody' by default on methods

Comment: Yes,right.I'm just giving an example.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let me start with your last question

> Is 2 better than 1, in performance?

No, there is no difference in the performance.

> I find that 2 is harder to use than 1

That is absolutely based on individual preference. May be you are used to imperative style of programming. And hence you feel it easy to write(Trust me after a while you would feel the same with Router Functions as well)

Basically Router Functions are one step towards functional style of programming. Spring wanted users to have the flexibility to configure routes in functional style.
Apart from this there is no difference between Controllers and Router Functions.

Comment: Well. Thank you very much! I understand part of it.

Comment: @MrXionGe which part did you not understand

Comment: First, thanks for your concern.
About Mono and Flux.What's the difference between using Mono or Flux and not using it?
I don't think they have much difference in performance.Because I make a test by JMeter

Comment: Your original question has nothing to do with "What's the difference between using Mono or Flux"

Answer (score 1):

If we leave individual preference, there is one explicit difference in filters.

The WebFlux framework provides two types of filters: ***WebFilters*** and ***HandlerFilterFunctions***.

The main difference between them is that WebFilter implementations work for all endpoints and HandlerFilterFunction implementations will only work for Router-based ones.

Comment: Thank you so much.There is no Interceptors in WebFlux. Of course,WebFilter is esay...

Answer (score 1):

The RouterFunction has a similar purpose as the annotation. However, there is an important distinction: with the annotation, your route is limited to what can be expressed through the annotation values.

Comment: please can you give one or two example where functional configuration can go further than annotaion?

Comment: https://jivimberg.io/blog/2018/05/20/spring-functional-router/ - please look at this article